# Predicting outcomes of chess games based on engine evaluation of current position

Tags: classification, dataset, games

I wish to train a classifier for chess games. For any given chess position, you can use one or more chess engines to give the position a numeric score (evaluation). A score less than 0 indicates that black is *more likely* to win. A score greater than 0 indicates that white is *more likely* to win. A score close to 0 indicates a good chance of draw.

I have a dataset of many games between two specific opponents *White* and *Black*, who always play white and black respectively. For each position in this dataset, I can evaluate the position with chess engine(s) to get an evaluation. I then divide these evaluations into three classes after some pre-processing to account for who is white and black. The three classes are 1) *White wins*, 2) *Black wins* and 3) *draw*.

The issue comes when dealing with the nature of the data:

- Suppose white wins a game, and at some point in that game, the position had evaluation +0.5. Then I want the classifier to consider this datapoint to actually represent the interval $[0.5,\infty)$.
- Suppose black wins a game, and at some point in that game, the position had evaluation -0.5. Then I want the classifier to consider this datapoint to actually represent the interval $(-\infty,-0.5]$.
- Suppose a game is a draw, and at some point in that game, the position had evaluation +0.2. Then I want the classifier to consider this datapoint to actually represent the interval $[0,0.2]$. Another position had evaluation -0.2. Then I want the classifier to consider this datapoint to actually represent the interval $[-0.2,0]$.

How can I achieve this when giving training data to the classifiers? What classifier should I use? Ideally this should be able to deal with evaluations from multiple engines, which means the feature space will be multidimensional and highly correlated. The final goal is to get the probability of each possible outcome, given the evaluation of the current position in a fresh game not in the dataset.

Comment: Chess engines already produce scores >.5 to indicate stronger probabilities than .5 entails of White winning. Why would you want to treat .5 the same as any value >= .5?  And why would you want to replace a point estimate with an interval?

Comment: I want the classifier to be aware that all the samples in a class are in a contiguous region. In my experiments I have ended up with weird classifications where there were small regions of evaluation space where the game was high probability of draw in the middle of a region with high probability of win. This was due to the data containing a game where the opponent blundered and suddenly the outcome was draw. I want probability of draw to monotonically increase closer to 0, and probability of win to monotonically increase further from 0.

Comment: How about a mixture density network. I know a neural network might not be what you want, but it will basically predict a histogram (though it still is a mixture of Gaussians). However, you could just predict two variables: the bounds. That, however, is kind of messy because you will have to manually figure out which is the high and low bound. Another caveat is that all these methods rely on the fact that you have a finite interval. However, this sounds like more of a training data problem. Also, you could just do a simple moving or exponential average.